# Unfolding a third order tensor in mode 0

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I am trying to implement my own version of tensorly.unfold method, except I am limiting the input to be a third order tensor rather than tensor of any order. What tenderly does can be found below, specifically under unfold(X, 0): http://tensorly.org/stable/user_guide/tensor_basics.html#unfolding

The function so far looks like this.

```
def unfoldTensor(array, mode):
    """
    Unfold a third order tensor - "array" given a specific mode-"mode"
    """
    if mode == 0:
        flat(array)
    if mode == 1:
        pass
    if mode == 2:
        pass
```

In the case where mode == 0, I attempted the following. Basically creating a new empty np array, then looping through the argument array, and flattening and appending each element in said empty np array.

```
def flat(array):
    new_arr = np.empty((0,100), int) # Not sure yet how to create an empty np array, just took this from somewhere
    for arr in test:
        print(np.append(new_arr, arr.flatten()))
```

However, when I tried with an example, the output is missing [16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23].

```
X = np.array([[[0, 1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7]],[[8,9],[10,11],[12,13],[14,15]],[[16,17],[18,19],[20,21],[22,23]]])
flat(X)
>> [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
[ 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
```

I couldn't figure out what went wrong.
I also noticed the output of flat(X) does not look exactly like the output of unfold(X, 0) using Tensorly. What is wrong?

Comment: I caught my mistake as I was going through this just now! The for loop is looping through "test", when it should be looping the argument "array". My mistake. However, I'd still like a solution as to why the flat(X) output looks different from the tenderly method, as well as how to create an empty np array like [], and append elements in it. Thanks!